# How to install Ubuntu on Acer 4752?

Tags: installation

**How to install ubuntu on my Laptop??**

I'm trying to install ubuntu "ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386" on my laptop.. :)

here is my specs.. :

```
Manufacturer: Acer
Model: Aspire 4752
OS: Windows 7
CPU/Ram: 2.401 GHz / 3936 MB
Video Card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M
Sound Card: Realtek High Definition Audio Intel(R) Display Audio
```

Any ideas??...

Thanks,

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Just download an iso file, burn it to a cd or dvd, boot with that cd and follow the steps to install it.

You can also use an usb disc.

You can see al this info in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

Comment: thanks..
anyway,does my laptop support for ubuntu??..

Comment: Maybe you would only need to research your video card, google it along with the keyword **linux**.